# ag-grid export produces corrupt excel file when a cell contains the vertical tabulation symbol (U+000B)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have a table with lots of data, some of it originating from an external source which i can't adjust or change. Some cells in the table contain a vertical tabulation symbol (U+000B). If those cells get exported, the generated excel file is corrupt: Excel tells me that it encountered problem with the file and provides the option to restore the information in the file. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

If i filter out the cells which contain the vertical tabulation symbol, everything works fine.

I could implement the `processCellCallback` callback to iterate over each cell and check for the special symbol, but that does not seem like a good solution.

Did anyone encounter a similiar problem with the ag-grid export functionalities?

Comment: can you prepare an example on stackblitz or plinkr ? and if it exactly as you said - I will create a ticked for ag-grid dev team.

Comment: [Plnkr Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/I3CxsVycKG5L4OBE?preview) The very first cell contains the symbol. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you provide a link to the ticket so i can keep track of it? Thank you!